# What is the distinction between clinical significance and statistical significance?

Tags: statistics, inference, significance

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_significance
The Link says
"Jacobson-Truax is common method of calculating clinical significance. It involves calculating a Reliability Change Index (RCI). The RCI equals the difference between a participant's pre-test and post-test scores, divided by the standard error of the difference."

This explanation is testing whether the difference in
effect-size estimates is statistically significant or not? Thus it does not check for "clinical" significance of effect-size of say, a new treatment.What is the correct way to distinguish clinical significance from statistical significance ?

Comment: It divides by the standard error or standard deviation? They are related terms yet not synonymous, and the difference matters a great deal in this situation. // https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81796/247274

Comment: True S.D. = sample s.d. 
 (observed) - sampling error. The sampling error is estimated.

Comment: The sampling error is estimated by using observed S.D. and sample-size. Please understand sampling theory if   you want a clearer picture. The sampling error fluctuates with a change in sample-size. The authors of formula clearly say - difference is divided by standard error and not by standard deviation. nice quarry!

Comment: If something depends on the sample size, then it sounds much more like statistical than clinical/practical significance.

Comment: please read my answer once again. The formula computes statistical significance.

Comment: Your first line calls it a clinical significance formula.

Comment: I have added the link in text to clarify. please read  further beginning  This explanation ...